# Remove first comma from on-the-fly string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, explode

As I'm a bit of php noob, I'm not sure whether to go with `preg_replace()` or to `explode()` then `implode()`.  Either way, I don't know how to go about it.

I'm in wordpress, and I'm running this code:

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'jobtype');
foreach($terms as $term){echo ', ' . $term->name;} ?>
```

I need to capture into a string the `echo ', ' . $term->name;` and remove that first `', '`.

Even if there's a different way I can `echo` the term names, could you guys (and gals) help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to replace the first ',' by what ?

Comment: @yokoloko If you look at the topic, I just want to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old school:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'jobtype');
$names = array();
foreach($terms as $term){
    $names[] = $term->name;
}
echo implode(',', $names);
```

---

As PHP 5.3 introduced [anonymous functions *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), [`array_map` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) becomes more interesting for these "one time" jobs:

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function($term) { return $term->name; }, 
                            wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'jobtype')));
```

Or maybe more descriptive with a reusable function:

```
function getProperty($prop) {
    return function($object) use ($prop) {
        return $object->{$prop};
    }
}

echo implode(',', array_map(getProperty('name'), 
                            wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'jobtype')));
```

But as said, this only works if you use PHP 5.3.

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm not in the mood to look if my host supports PHP 5.3, so I'll just use what works.  Thanks so much!